# The argument type 'Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I want after Login return me data to specific user. To get it i will do query which  searches the documents for the ID that the user sent to the userId field automatically during registration
but when i want to induce my query give me error:
*The argument type 'Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>?'*

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing right now is fetching a collection of users that match on that criteria, which will return you a list (hence QuerySnapshot). If you want the single document associated with the logged in user (a DocumentSnapshot),  you'd have to do:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user!.uid).get()
```

which should return a Future with a **DocumentSnapshot**, and you can capture its data in the **builder** callback handler of the **FutureBuilder** via the snapshot provided in the callback.

Comment: yeah that's what i need thank you